# Oracle SQL Select Only 5 Digit Row in a Column

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax

[image]

```sql
    SELECT * 
    FROM GNGRB.CLAIM 
    WHERE ZOCRECDT IS NOT NULL;
```

SLNO  Column select only 5 digit row

Comment: Hello @ownmurad WHAT ? I do not believe anyone can understand this question ?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve]

Comment: Column data type?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please use length function of oracle. For e.g:

```
select * 
from table a 
where length(a.column_name) = 5
```

In your case

```
SELECT * 
FROM GNGRB.CLAIM 
WHERE ZOCRECDT IS NOT NULL 
and LENGTH(SLNO) = 5
```

Comment: This will select columns that have exactly 5 characters but not 5 digits ? You are sure this is what OP wants ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM GNGRB.CLAIM WHERE LENGTH (SLNO) = 5;      --What's wrong with this code?

Comment: I have select any column 5 digit number row

Comment: My answer would select only rows whose length of column SLNO is 5, as asked in the question, as OP wants "SLNO Colum select only 5 digit row"

Comment: Hi @SumairGulzar character is not a digit !? So your answer to my question has no meaning... Your query will select values with exactly 5 characters long. Maybe OP needs digit/number only as he mentioned: "SLNO Colum select only 5 digit row". But The question is so bad that we can not know what he wanted exactly and that is my queston to you. How do YOU know from this question what does OP want ?